# Using Material icon with

Tags: typescript, react-native, material-ui

I am new to React native so sorry if the question is dump.

I would like to use the icon in material icons from https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/ in my material bottom nav bar from react navigation.

But the example given here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/ is using material community icons. How can I change it to icons listed in https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/? Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Trips"
          component={HomeScreen}

// Here is the error
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Trips",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="travel-explore" color={color} size={26} />,
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```